# Unexpected behavior of a function using getMaxRows() method

Tags: google-apps-script

I've built this function to insert a dropdown list in blank rows. It was invoked each time the sheet was edited. But, instead of only inserting the lists in the blank rows, the function added thousands of new rows (with the dropdownlists). Any tip why this happened?

```
function insertDropdownList(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();        
    var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, getColumnNrByName(sheet, "COLUMN NMAE")+1, sheet.getMaxRows());
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['value 1', 'value2'], true).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: Are you using new sheets?

Comment: No, @ZigMandel, it's the old ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found was replace the use of `.getMaxRows()` by some other number, like `5`. So I got the dropdownlist in the next 5 rows.